# What is the actual advantage of using let/block scoping?

Tags: ecmascript-6, let

I can't seem to see the actual advantage of using `let`. Sure, if I have a for loop I would use `let i = 0` instead of `var i = 0` and `i` would now belong to the scope of the for loop block. But is that really advantageous? I mean I can use var and have the variable have function scope access but just not use it where I don't need to? What is the advantage to block scoping ?

I understand the difference between var and let, I want a more coherent understanding of `let`'s particular advantages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["let" keyword vs "var" keyword in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/let-keyword-vs-var-keyword-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already mentioned one advantage: Block scope in loops. This avoids issues with [defining functions inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196), which I'd argue is one of the biggest pitfalls for people new to JavaScript:

```js
// With var
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.var');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].onclick = function() {
    console.log("I'm element #" + (i + 1) + ".");
  };
}

// With let
elements = document.querySelectorAll('.let');
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].onclick = function() {
    console.log("I'm element #" + (i + 1) + ".");
  };
}
```

```html
<h3>With <code>var</code></h3>
<div class="var">Click me!</div>
<div class="var">Click me!</div>

<h3>With <code>let</code></h3>
<div class="let">Click me!</div>
<div class="let">Click me!</div>
```

Another advantage is that `let` variables aren't initialized by default. This makes it easier to catch mistakes when trying to access a variable with the same name in a higher scope:

```js
// With `var`, we get `undefined` which can be tricky to debug in more
// complex code.
var foo = 42;

function bar() {
  console.log(foo); // undefined
  var foo = 21;
}
bar();
```

```js
// With `let`, we get a ReferenceError, which makes it clear that we made
// a mistake here.
var foo = 42;

function bar() {
  console.log(foo); // ReferenceError
  let foo = 21;
}
bar();
```

---

All in all this aligns JavaScript more with how other languages work.

Comment: Just to make sure I get this. So in the first example foo is not 42 as soon as bar() is called it becomes undefined because it has been declared with var inside the function again right?

Comment: Thank you, will read more on the advantages of defining functions inside the loop. So would it be correct to say that variables declared with let are not hoisted?

Comment: (I added an example regarding functions...) There has been quite some discussion around this, because different people associate different meaning with "hoisting". But the answer is yes: Hoisting means that the variable is declared *and* initialized to a default value (`undefined`). `let` declarations are declared, but not initialized by default. They are still shadowing outer variables with the same name though.

Comment: Wow thank you very much for the code snippet. Totally see an application of block scoping now.